# Mysql select based on other select

Tags: mysql, case

dears i have below query that's gets the count based on cases and it's working fine

```
select users.firstName,users.lastName,users.id,users.phoneNumber,
count(CASE
        WHEN orders.`orderStatus` = 4 THEN 1 ELSE null END) As completed,
        count(CASE
        WHEN orders.`orderStatus`  = 5 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as CustomerCancelled,
        count(CASE
        WHEN orders.`orderStatus`  = 11 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as providerCancelled,
        count(`orders`.`createdAt`) as total,
        from users,providers,orders
        where
        `orders`.`providerId` = `providers`.`id`
        and
        users.id = `providers`.userId
        and
        `orders`.`createdAt` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
        GROUP BY users.id;
```

what I need to add is to get the count for CustomerCancelled/total and show it with each record

I tried to divide it like below but not working

```
select users.firstName,users.lastName,users.id,users.phoneNumber,
count(CASE
        WHEN orders.`orderStatus` = 4 THEN 1 ELSE null END) As completed,
        count(CASE
        WHEN orders.`orderStatus`  = 5 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as CustomerCancelled,
        count(CASE
        WHEN orders.`orderStatus`  = 11 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as providerCancelled,
        count(`orders`.`createdAt`) as total,
        CustomerCancelled/total //// this is what i tried to do
        from users,providers,orders
        where
        `orders`.`providerId` = `providers`.`id`
        and
        users.id = `providers`.userId
        and
        `orders`.`createdAt` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
        GROUP BY users.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use aliases in the `SELECT` part of the query. You need to explicitly write out the expression:

```
select users.firstName,
       users.lastName,
       users.id,
       users.phoneNumber,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN orders.`orderStatus` = 4 THEN 1 END) aS completed,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN orders.`orderStatus` = 5 THEN 1 END) AS CustomerCancelled,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN orders.`orderStatus`  = 11 THEN 1 END) AS providerCancelled,
       COUNT(`orders`.`createdAt`) AS total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN orders.`orderStatus`  = 5 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(`orders`.`createdAt`) AS ratio_cancelled
FROM users
JOIN providers
JOIN orders
WHERE `orders`.`providerId` = `providers`.`id`
  AND users.id = `providers`.userId
  AND `orders`.`createdAt` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY users.id;
```

Note that you don't need an `ELSE null` in your `CASE` expressions as that is the default. Also you should write explicit `JOIN` statements rather than use the deprecated comma style implicit `JOIN`.